# how important is setting max fd on select?

Tags: c, multithreading, select, pipe

Within an infinite loop, I am listening 100+ file descriptors using select. If fd has some packets ready to be read, I notify the packet processor thread assigned to this file descriptor and I don't set the bit for this file descriptor for the next round until I receive a notification from data processor thread saying it is done. I wonder how inefficient my code would be if I won't calculate the max. fd for select everytime I clear/set a file descriptor from the set. I am expecting file descriptors to be nearly contiguous, data arrival rate to be a few thousands bytes every second for each fd.

Comment: Is there reason you don't just do maxfd=sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX);

Comment: Try setting it to `0` and seee what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really use `poll` instead of `select`. Both are standard, but `poll` is easier to use, does not place a limit on the number of file descriptors you can check (whereas `select` limits you to the compile-time constant `FD_SETSIZE`), and more efficient. If you do use `select`, you can always pass `FD_SETSIZE` for the first argument, but this will of course give worst-case performance since the kernel has to scan the whole `fd_set`; passing the actual max+1 allows a shorter search, but still not as efficient as the array passed to `poll`.

For what it's worth, these days it seems stylish to use the nonstandard Linux `epoll` or whatever the BSD equivalent is. These interfaces may have some advantages if you have a huge number (on the order of tens of thousands) of long-lived (at least several round trips) connections, but otherwise performance will not be noticably better (and, at the lower end, may be worse), and these interfaces are of course non-portable, and in my opinion, harder to use correctly than the plain, portable `poll`.

Answer (score 2):

It is in principle important to give a good max fd to `select` (but with only a few hundreds of file descriptors in your process that does not matter much).

But `select` is becoming obsolete (precisely because of the max fd, so the kernel will take *O(m)* time where *m* is the max.fd; so `select` could be costly if using it on a small set of file descriptors whose max *m* is large). Use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead (which, when given a set of *n* file descriptors takes *O(n)* time, independently of the maximal file descriptor *m*).

Current Linux systems and processes might have many dozens of thousands of file descriptors. Read about the [C10K problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k).

And you might have some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), e.g. use libraries like [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) (which might use ̀`poll` internally, and may use more operating system specific things like `epoll` etc... abstracting them in a convenient interface)